# How to get Azure storage account access key from Azure key vault

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I have an Azure storage account and an Azure key vault created. I have configured the key vault to manage the storage account access key and rotate the keys with a rotation policy. I have also setup Azure AD credentials for my java application to access the Key vault. But I couldn’t find anything in the Azure documentation about accessing storage account access key from key vault. 
Does anyone know if it is possible to retrieve the storage account keys from key vault?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=get+azure+storage+key+from+key+vault+java&t=brave&ia=web

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not supported to retrieve the storage account keys from key vault.

Please raise [user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) or else there is [similar user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/38015650-support-pulling-storage-account-key-from-azure-key) on you can up vote.